# Magento 2 reindex price/clear cache for specific products

Tags: magento2, cache, indexing, full-page-cache

I am having some issues doing this programmatically - I have tried a few methods but the price before the change remains.

Basically, I want to reindex pricing for a select number of products, and then clear cache so the new price will display immediately.

The code reindexes individual products - but cache remains uncleared (old price still visible on category page/product page):

```
$ids = array_unique($ids);
/* \Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer */
$indexer = $this->_indexer->load('catalog_product_price');

if (!$indexer->isScheduled()) {

    $indexer->reindexList($ids);
}
foreach ($ids as $id) {
    $product = $this->_product->loadByAttribute('entity_id', $id);
    $identities = $product->cleanCache();
    foreach ($identities as $identity) {
        /* \Magento\Framework\Indexer\CacheContext */
        $this->_cacheContext->registerEntities($identities, $ids);

        /* \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface */
        $this->_eventManager->dispatch('clean_cache_by_tags', ['object' => $this->_cacheContext]);
}
```

I have gone through a few variations of the above, none with the desired result.

This code causes an error:

```
  /* \Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Product\Price */
  $this->_priceIndexer->executeList($ids)
```

Error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '758-0-    1' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index_price_tmp` SELECT `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`entity_id`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`customer_group_id`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`website_id`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`tax_class_id`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`orig_price` AS `price`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`price` AS `final_price`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`min_price`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`max_price`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`tier_price` FROM `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp` WHERE (entity_id in (139, 1204, 748, 1026, 1027, 758, 1030, 1031, 1043, 788, 927, 928))"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clean product cache using Object manager. It is not recommended nowadays though:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$cacheManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\CacheInterface');
$cacheManager->clean('catalog_product_' . $productID);
```

If Varnish cache is on, it should be considered too. [Check this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42636405/3733214)

But I use a little different approach for product prices which works fine:

1. Setup prices update script where `catalog_product_entity_decimal` table is updated.
2. Cron job runs script, reindexes and flushes cache using CLI

> /usr/bin/php /home/[domain]/public_html/cron-prices.php &&
>   /usr/bin/php /home/[domain]/public_html/bin/magento indexer:reindex
>   catalog_product_price catalog_product_flat && /usr/bin/php
>   /home/[domain]/public_html/bin/magento cache:flush eav