# Magento 1.14.4.0: Programmatically clear cache of individual product

Tags: magento-enterprise, cache, full-page-cache, magento-1.14, block-cache

I need to clear the cache for individual product. For example, If admin change any detail/price/qty of product. I need to run script that clear the cache for that particular product only. I am running script which clear the cache for all products but I need to do it for single product. I am running script from route of Magento.

```
<?php
require_once("app/Mage.php");
Mage::app();
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(1);
$type = 'BLOCK_HTML';
Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Cache::getCacheInstance()
            ->cleanType($type);
echo "success";
```

Please suggest. Thank you in advance.

Comment: refer this link if it's relevant to you **https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/232292/73212**

Comment: Thanks, @MohitRane That solution belongs to m2. I wanted solution for m1. :)